# Empty email body on iPad using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, email, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to add sharing to my app.  Everything works on iPhone as expected, but on iPad, the mail view controller is brought up after tapping on the email icon of 'UIActivityViewController' but the body of the email does not get set (with `text1`) and the email viewController is inactive and does not allow the user to enter recipients.

```
            let text1 = "this is the body of the email"
            self.finalizeDocument()
            let controller = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [text1], applicationActivities: nil)
            controller.setValue("Siged document is attached", forKey: "subject")
            if let ppc = controller.popoverPresentationController {
                ppc.barButtonItem = self.shareButton!
            }
            self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that rebooting the iPad fixed the problem.

Comment: Crazy, but here was the same, after turn off and turn on the code starts to work.

Answer (score 0):

hey try something like this

1. import the message lib
2. add the mail delegate to the class
3. compose and send your message

   ```
   import MessageUI

   class ViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate{

       func someAwesomeFunction(){
            var subjectText = “ OMG  a subject”
            var bodtText = “ YOLO”

            var picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
            picker.setSubject(subjectText)
            picker.setMessageBody(bodtText, isHTML: true)

            presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is to use the UIActivityViewControl which allows sharing with mail, messages, Facebook, Twitter, etc using the same controller.